# C:Url not appending the localhost to my javascript file

Tags: javascript

So I am currently getting a

```
 Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

After looking it on for a while I was able to determine it happens when you try to upload javascript files from local and not http that issue occurs.

My jsp on back end

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
  <head>  
    <title>Product Finder</title>  
   </head>
    <body ng-app="myProductFinder">

        <div class="generic-container" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchString" id="uname" class="username form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>

            <input type="submit"  value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        </form>                              

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/app.js' />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/service/productSearchService.js' />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value='/static/js/controller/productSearchController.js' />"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My rendered page on fron end source**

```
<html>
  <head>  
    <title>Product Finder</title>  
   </head>
    <body ng-app="myProductFinder">

        <div class="generic-container" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchString" id="uname" class="username form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>

            <input type="submit"  value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        </form>                              

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/searchMart/static/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/searchMart/static/js/service/productSearchService.js"></script>
        <script src="/searchMart/static/js/controller/productSearchController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you look at the script on last 3 lines it is pointing to local path and not through localhost which I would expect it to go through. I am using jetty to run it. Does anyone know why it is not picking the local host url

Answer (score 0):

I was not putting http:// in my get request in my service js.

```
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/searchMart/index/search',productName)
```